# React and Express not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, frontend, backend

I was moving my React frontend folder into my collaborator's Express backend folder, here's the file structure.

[image]

This is app.js which we use to render the website.

```js
const express = require("express")
const path = require("path")
const app = express()
const dotenv = require("dotenv")

//setup
dotenv.config()
app.use(express.json())
app.use(require("cors")())

//routes
app.use("/api/auth", require("./api/authRoute"))
app.use("/api/user", require("./api/userRoute"))


//serve frontend
const frontendPath = path.join(__dirname,"build","pneumonia-project")
app.use(express.static(frontendPath))
app.get("*",(req,res)=>{
   res.sendFile(frontendPath+"/public/index.html")
})

app.listen(8000,()=>{
   console.log("Server Started")
})
```

And this is the index.html in the public folder

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="public/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="public/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="public/manifest.json" />
    <title>Pneumo Scanner</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've just solved the `Manifest: line: 1, column: 1, syntax error` problem. Now the logo is showed, but none of the components in the src folder is rendered. 
Is there any problem with the routing or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Alright I've solved this. Turns out I can only send a HTML file, React components aren't supported. So I have to use `npm run build` to generate an actual build folder to make it work.